# I want to print to a new line in the 'terminal' (UITextView) but whenever I hit the done button, it just replaces what's there

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is the method I wrote to add a little 'ConsoleCalc' prefix to each output. The terminal is a UITextView

```
-(void)writeToTerminal:(NSString *)string {
    self.terminal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ConsoleCalc > %@ \n", string];
}
```

You can see the '\n' that I put to try to make it add a new line. But whenever I enter a new input the TextView just replaces whatever was there with the new result of my input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
self.terminal.text = [self.terminal.text stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\nConsoleCalc > %@", string]];
```

Comment: @codelnOrange No, that's not the problem. I'm happy with the method I have here. What I want to know how to do is how to make a new line in the text view whenever text is output to it.

Comment: @blockaj Ok my bad, this stops it from just overwriting itself everytime though

Comment: @blockaj also added newline in there for you

Answer (score 1):

You have to capture the current text value, then append your new string to the current text:

```
NSString *currentText = [self.terminal.text copy];
NSString *newLine = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ConsoleCalc > %@ \n",string];
NSString *newText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",currentText,newLine];
self.terminal.text = newText;
```

Comment: may also try \r for return key. I've never tried passing a \n to a textView

Comment: Whats your reasoning behind creating three new strings to do this?

Comment: When showing people things I prefer verbose to concise, that's all

Answer (score 1):

@CodeInOrange's answer is technically correct, but it can be nicely shortened using `stringByAppendingFormat:` instead of appending `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`

```
-(void)writeToTerminal:(NSString *)string
{
    [self.teminal setText:[self.teminal.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"ConsoleCalc > %@ \n",string]];
}
```